# anguar2 nativescript error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.router')"

Tags: angular2-routing, nativescript

I am new to Angular2 Native script Programming... i need to navigate one page to another. i am stuck with the typeError:"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.router')" plz help me out..
my code is given..

//page1.ts

```
public constructor(private router: Router) { }
getMyDrawing(args) {
    let pad = this.DrawingPad.nativeElement;
    let img: Image = this.signImage.nativeElement;
    let drawingImage;
    pad.getDrawing().then
    (
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            drawingImage = data;
            img.src=data;
            this.router.navigate(['page2']);
        }

    );
}
```

//routing.ts

```
import { DrawingPadExample } from "./app.component";
import { Page2Component } from "./app.page2";

export const routes = [
  {   path: "drawing-pad-example", component: DrawingPadExample},
   {   path: "page2", component: Page2Component }
];

 export const navigatableComponents = [
 DrawingPadExample,
 Page2Component
 ];
```

//module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-
angular/nativescript.module";
import { DrawingPadExample } from "./app.component";
import { routes, navigatableComponents } from "./app.routing";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-
angular/router";
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        DrawingPadExample
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        DrawingPadExample,
        ...navigatableComponents
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have injected router to that component?

Comment: @slesh you mean... _import {Router, NavigationExtras} from "@angular/router";_

Answer (score 1):

When you say navigation is not working, do you nothing at all happens and no errors are generated?

I would advice you try putting the callback within a zoneCallback.

```
public constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router){
}

public getMyDrawing(args) {
    let pad = this.DrawingPad.nativeElement;
    let img: Image = this.signImage.nativeElement;
    let drawingImage;

    pad.getDrawing().then((data) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => { 
            console.log(data);
            drawingImage = data;
            img.src=data;
            this.router.navigate(['page2']);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: why this is necessary ?

Comment: Something about if a particular process runs outside of Angular's changeDetection strategy.

Answer (score 0):

@JBR, No, I mean dependency injection using constructor, for example,

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

add that line to you page1 component.

***Update***

replace this

```
function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        drawingImage = data;
        img.src=data;
        this.router.navigate(['page2']);
    }
```

with arrow function

```
(data) => {
        console.log(data);
        drawingImage = data;
        img.src=data;
        this.router.navigate(['page2']);
    }
```

Comment: all ready initialized!!! _public constructor(private router: Router) { }_

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need alway use arrow function to keep this context. Otherwise, you need bind function to this context manually.

Comment: It will be productive if you would share the whole project code. I think there is an error in routing configuration.  Few points to check:

1. Have you added <base href="/"></base> to index.html
2. When you navigate using Rotuer, url should starts from slash(/)

Comment: index.html? where i can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Add instance in constructor for router.

```
constructor(private router : Router){}
```

because as error stated `typeError:"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.router')"` you are trying to access
this.router which is not initilized yet

Comment: all ready initialized!!! _public constructor(private router: Router) { }_ but error exists..

Comment: then there must be a error of scope variable `this`

Comment: try to replace your function declaration with arrow function.

Comment: i replaced it with arrow function.. now no error.. but not navigating to next page

Comment: simple try replacing by navigateByURL like this `this.router.navigateByUrl('page2');`

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug when I was passing a function between two components.

In the first component, I imported `Router`, but in the second I didn't. Make sure that you import all necessary libraries when you are using callback functions.